# Should mini projects have their own repositories on GitHub?

Tags: github

I tried a few searches related to this questions on here and didn't see something similar.

As part of a bootcamp I am working on, I have a few mini-projects I have to submit. These projects take between 2-10 hours to complete and typically only contain 1-5 files each. I've seen other students have separate repositories for each of the projects, which allows them to have a clean readme.txt. Initially, I grouped these mini projects into folders within one repository dedicated to these mini projects to reduce clutter. So I can see potential advantages to either approach. At either rate, these small projects were designed to demonstrate very specific skills that are relevant to future employers, so I want them to be available for inspection.

So is there a "best practice" if I am intending to use GitHub as a portfolio of my code? Would it be better to declutter my repositories by keeping small projects together so my bigger projects can shine? Or to separate them so each project is readily in-sight?

Answer (score 1):

> have separate repositories for each of the projects, which allows them to have a clean `readme.txt`.

You can have a clean `readme.txt`/`readme.md` with *one* repo, which would:

- explain what the subfolder represents
- list your subfolders
- link to sub-readme.md (one `readme.md` per subfolder, per project)

That being said, you can create an account dedicated for this bootcamp, and keep your repos separate, that way you avoid the clutter with your main GitHub account.